# Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeTcpBinding self hosting

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have created a class library which have Datacontract and service contract and its implementation. Then I created a console application to host the wcf service. Where i have defined WCF setting in app.config file which is below.
    `<configuration>
     <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
       <service name="TestService.TestService"                         behaviorConfiguration="tcpbindingConfiguration">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net:tcp://FullComputerName:9002/TestService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="net:tcp://FullComputerName:9002/TestService" binding="netTcpBinding"                                          contract="TestService.ITestServiceContract"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding"   contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
     </services>
       <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="tcpbindingConfiguration">
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
       </system.serviceModel>
     <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
     </startup>
    </configuration>`

Then I program.cs File.

```
       ServiceHost sh = null;

        try
        {
            sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService.TestService));
            sh.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Service started at net:tcp//FullComputerName:9002/TestService");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sh = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Service  cann't started");
            throw;
        }
```

I have activate the WCF for Non HTTP from windows features on and off.

I want to host this wcf service in console application, Some article suggest that i need to set nettcp binding in IIS. Why i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS is an alternative hosting for your WCF service, that is you either host it in your console application or in IIS. As far as I understand, there should be no need to setup IIS, if you use a console application.

Try changing "net:tcp" in your configuration to "net.tcp".

Comment: still getting "Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [net]."

Comment: It works, After that i get another error that is "The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address." I resolve this by removing httpGetEnabled="true" from serviceMetadata attribute.  Thanks Korli.